# React, javascript object, if key value exists render an element

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

How do I check to see if a javascript object item has a key and render an element if it does exist.

This is my javascript object which is then parsed through and each `item` is made into a bootstrap list item.  Under `items.title = Groups`, there is an additional key `"dropdown": "true"` which is the element I would like to create a dropdown menu for.

```
var linksNav = {
    items: [
        {
            "type": "heading",
            "title": "News",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self"
        },
        {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "People",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self"
        },
        {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Events",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self"
        },
        {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Groups",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self",
            "dropdown": "true"
        },
        {
            "type": "heading",
            "title": "Capabilities",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self"
        },
        {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Initiatives",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_self"
        },
        {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Who we are",
            "href": "#",
            "target": "_blank"
        },
    ]
}
```

And this is my code (that doesn't work) to try to conditionally render a dropdown (the `<NavSub />` tag) if that key exists for that menu item.
The result I get is my dropdown menu for each of my list items is `<div>Nothing</div>`.  Everything else shows up as normal, so I figure there's something wrong with my conditional statement.

```
render: function() {
  let dropdownMenu;        
  if (this.props.dropdown=="true") {
    dropdownMenu = (<Navsub />)
  } else {
     dropdownMenu = (<div>Nothing</div>)
  }
  return (
    <li className={this.props.title + ' nav-items'}>
      <a href={this.props.href} target={this.props.target} className={this.state.color + ' dropdown-toggle'} onClick={this.onClick} data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{this.props.title}</a>

      //I want to conditionall render this dropdown menu
      <ul className="dropdown-menu fade">
        {dropdownMenu}
      </ul>

    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: *"that doesn't work"* What exactly doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Or not the output you expect? If so, what are you getting and what do you expect?

Comment: *"nothing shows up"* None of the elements you are creating in your example are visible (e.g. the link)? Or do you mean that just the `<ul className="dropdown-menu fade">` element is empty? If you really don't get any output at all, are you getting an error? If yes, what is the error? Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Edited.  Not really the output I expected but then again I am new to react.

Comment: @Snorlax When posting a problem, focus on actual vs expected behavior and error messages `I expected the screen to display A,B,C but it displays DEF instead (or I get a JS error: "blah blah blah")`

Comment: What do you receive as props in your component. Can you console.log(this.props) in the render and share the result

Answer (score 1):

If "dropdown" may not be present in your props, you should use JavaScript's [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). Also, avoid using `==` as it can lead to weird results due to silent type conversions.

```
if ('dropdown' in this.props && this.props.dropdown === 'true') {
  //show dropdown
} else {
  //don't show dropdown
}
```

The previous snippet works because JavaScript's `if` [short-circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Having said that, given that you're getting a div containing `Nothing` in each dropdown, it's likely your components are not receiving the props they're supposed to. You should check what props each component is getting.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `if(this.props.dropdown)`?  If it's not present, it evaluates as `undefined`, which is falsey.

Comment: Well, yes, but they are using a string, which makes me think `this.props.dropdown` may have values other than `true`, `false` or not present, so this is the most reliable way.

Comment: If `this.props.dropdown` can never be something other than `true`, `false` or not present, then your way is better, but in that case they should be using a boolean anyway.

Comment: fair enough, that's definitely a better way to be certain of being sure.

Answer (score 0):

This approach may be *overkill* for your situation where the following will work for your situation:

```
if ((this.props.dropdown) && this.props.dropdown === "true"){
  dropdownMenu = <Navsub />;
} else {
  dropdownMenu = <div>Nothing</div>
}
```

---

**An alternative approach** to checking whether the property `dropdown` ***exists***  on the object `this.props`, you can use [Object#hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) with the shortcut `&&` binary operator in your condition:

```
// the condition will only check if dropdown is true if it exists on this.props
if (this.props.hasOwnProperty('dropdown') && this.props.dropdown === "true") {
  dropdownMenu = <Navsub />;
} else {
  dropdownMenu = <div>Nothing</div>
}
```

> [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is useful in scenarios where you want to
>   ensure that the property exists on the object ***even in the case where
>   its value is `null` or `undefined`***.